# Call redux state props from react navigationOptions

Tags: react-native

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
```

This is main home component:

```js
const Homes = props => {
    return()
}
```

This is navigation header title of main Homes component:

```js
    Homes.navigationOptions = {
      title: 'home',
    };
```

This is redux connect with Homes component:

```js
    const mapStateToProps = ({
      user: {
        user
      },
      language: {
        lang
      }
    }) => {
      return {
        user,
        lang
      }
    }

    const Home = connect(mapStateToProps, {

    })(Homes)

    export { Home }
```

Comment: what's the problem that you are facing?. please mention that

Comment: I want to call redux props 'user' from Homes.navigationOptions. @VahidAkhtar